# What does extern do in objective C?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, extern

If you extern a C++ method (not a variable) in an objective C file, what does this even do? What does it allow you to do? Especially in the context of an iPhone app.

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to call a method which resides externally of your C file

Answer (score 3):

`extern` is a C *keyword* that lets the programmer specify some construct (function or variable) that can be exported to other modules.

Is is said that C supports *modularization* but he does not permit a correct separation from implementation and interface of a module (so no *encapsulation*). `extern` is all it offers.

[Here](http://www.fast-product-development.com/modular_programming.html)'s a link for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ method is basically a C function, C functions are extern by default (in the prototype anyway).  It just means that the function is not implemented there, although usually it means that its in another compilation unit (file).  Obviously, most C functions / C++ methods are implemented in another file, which is why they are extern by default.  Long story short, it does nothing.